# Is it possible to locate all comments I've entered on all WordPress blogs?

Tags: comments, wordpress.com

WordPress sure seem to know who I am as I only have to enter my email address & name for my little avatar to appear when commenting on others' blogs, but I was wondering if there is any way that I can locate all comments I've made on all WordPress blogs?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress uses gravatars just like StackExchange sites [source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars).  Gravatar uses a hash of your email to identify you and return your avatar.  By providing your email (same one you use here?), that's all Gravatar needs.

Other than trying to do a search on Google or your preferred search engine, I don't think this would be possible.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realise they used Gravatar.  I just assumed that I'd signed up to something on Wordpress.com at some point in the past.

Comment: Automattic, the wordpress.com folks, *own* Gravatar :-)