# How can I search WordPress comments?

Tags: search, comments, wordpress.com

I can easily search a WordPress.com hosted blog by doing the following (on DDG):

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ff1metrics.wordpress.com%2F%20some%20search%20term

But how can I limit my search to comments *only*? And if possible, only to comments of a given user?

(Either solution would work for me, so this is NOT a duplicate of [Is it possible to locate all comments I've entered on all WordPress blogs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6287/is-is-possible-to-locate-all-comments-ive-entered-on-all-wordpress-blogs).)

So what I would like to achieve is to find whether commenter `user` posted `some term` on any post of this WordPress.com hosted blog.

Answer (score -1):

You should search by that specific name, for example:

```
SELECT author_name FROM all_authors WHERE author_name=david
```

Comment: I tried this approach: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ff1metrics.wordpress.com%2F+SELECT+author_name+FROM+all_authors+WHERE+author_name%3Df1metrics+blunder , but it doesn't seem to help. Could you give some details on how exactly this should be used?